# Performance ao gerar uma tabela em JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, tomcat

Estou com uma dúvida de como melhorar a `perfomance` ao gerar uma tabela em uma página usando componentes `JSF` e `Primefaces`.

Estou gerando uma tabela, após fazer uma consulta SQL e mapear o objeto usando `Hibernate`, mais especificamente, criando uma lista de objetos usando `ResultTransformer` interface.

Percebo que esta ok, fazendo TDD, ao chamar os dados o processamento é rápido.

Mas tem travado a página quando vai gerar ela.

O código da página é assim:

```
<c:if test="#{bean.pojo.relatorioExtratoLojista != null}">
    <c:forEach var="loja" items="#{bean.buscarLojas()}">
        <c:forEach var="filial" items="#{bean.buscarFilial(loja)}">
            <c:forEach var="atendente" items="#{bean.buscarAtendente(filial)}">
                <c:forEach var="propostaStatus" items="#{bean.buscarPropostaStatus(atendente)}">
                    <p:panelGrid 
                        styleClass="panelGridCenter gridNoBackground" 
                        style="width: 100%; white-space:nowrap;">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                           // colunas do cabeçalho
                        </f:facet>
                        <c:forEach var="propostaCartao" items="#{bean.buscarPropostasCartao(atendente, propostaStatus)}" varStatus="propostaCartaoVarStatus">
                          // dados da tabela
                        </c:forEach>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <br/>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Onde eu coloquei `// colunas do cabeçalho` é gerado o cabeçalho da tabela, e o comentário `// dados da tabela` tem os dados da tabela.

A estrutura é essa:

```
Map<Loja, Map<Filial, Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>>>> mapLoja
```

Alguns dos métodos do bean são:

```
public List<Loja> buscarLojas() {
    return new ArrayList<Loja>(this.getPojo().getRelatorioExtratoLojista().keySet());
}

public List<Filial> buscarFilial(Loja loja) {
    Map<Filial, Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>>> mapFilial = this.getPojo().getRelatorioExtratoLojista().get(loja);
    return new ArrayList<Filial>(mapFilial.keySet());
}

public List<Atendente> buscarAtendente(Filial filial) {
    Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>> mapAtendente = this.getPojo().getRelatorioExtratoLojista().
                                                                             get(filial.getLoja()).get(filial);
    return new ArrayList<Atendente>(mapAtendente.keySet());
}

public List<PropostaStatus> buscarPropostaStatus(Atendente atendente) {
    Map<Filial, Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>>> mapFilial = this.getPojo().getRelatorioExtratoLojista().get(atendente.getLoja());
    Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>> mapAtendente = mapFilial.get(atendente.getFilial());
    Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>> mapPropostaStatus = mapAtendente.get(atendente);
    if (NullUtil.isNull(mapPropostaStatus.keySet())) {
        toString();
    }
    return new ArrayList<PropostaStatus>(mapPropostaStatus.keySet());
}

public List<PropostaCartao> buscarPropostasCartao(Atendente atendente, PropostaStatus propostaStatus) {
    Map<Filial, Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>>> mapFilial = this.getPojo().getRelatorioExtratoLojista().get(atendente.getLoja());
    Map<Atendente, Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>>> mapAtendente = mapFilial.get(atendente.getFilial());
    Map<PropostaStatus, List<PropostaCartao>> mapPropostaStatus = mapAtendente.get(atendente);
    return new ArrayList<PropostaCartao>(mapPropostaStatus.get(propostaStatus));
}
```

Eu quando coloquei para `debugar` no `bean`, percebi que o método `buscarLojas()` é chamado muitas vezes, aparentemente mais que deveria.

Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para melhorar a performance, já que refiz a `query` para justamente diminuir a quantidade de dados.

Comment: Olá, notei que não existe LazyLoad, no caso, tudo é encontrado e mostrado de uma vez apenas, confere? Se sim, quantos registros são apresentados?

Comment: @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria isso é uma pergunta complicada, porque podem variar bastante, porque são dados onde o usuário pode escolher parametros no filtro como datas entre outras coisas, mas podem ser exibidos por exemplo mais de 10 mil registros.

Comment: Pode ser que o problema ai, não esteja no select, e sim na renderização da página, mesmo com elemento puramente html, 10 mil registros são capazes de travar consideravelmente seu navegador, no caso do JSF, isso certamente é pior uma vez que ainda existe todo um gerenciamento do DOM. Aconselho a criar uma paginação, provavelmente vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria não estou usando DataTable, tem como fazer paginação sem usar datatable.

Comment: No caso do JSF é mais difícil, pois o componente do data table se encarrega de abstrair as chamadas para próxima pagina, página anterior e coisas do tipo, possível é, mas não consigo lhe orientar.

Comment: @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria, obrigado e vou deixar em aberto para outras sugestões.

Comment: @Macario1983, qual o motivo de, uma vez que você faz uso do Primefaces, você não utilizar o componente dataTable?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares porque eu quis usar laço de repetição dentro da parte de dados das colunas e com a `datatable` não funcionou.

Comment: @RicardoRodriguesdeFaria eu troquei o componente para `ui:repeat` e o desempenho melhorou consideravelmente.

Comment: Você tentou usar o `p:treeTable`?

Comment: @WeslleyTavares desculpa, mas desconheço esse componente, o que me preocupa é que são tantas tabelas geradas que vai gerando muitas coisas...

Comment: Você vai ter que olhar a documentação (começando pelo showcase) do Primefaces. Lá você vai ver a implementação do conceito de treeTable e de paginação de forma bem mais esclarecedora (já que tem muito código pra analisar).

Comment: Que bom cara, acredito que se paginar resolve completamente o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para oficializarmos uma resposta.

O principal problema em questão, é a falta de uso do LazyLoad e não no select.
A renderização da página, mesmo com elemento puramente html, são capazes de travar consideravelmente seu navegador (você pode fazer o teste com tabelas acima das 500 linhas), no caso do JSF, o resultado é ainda pior, uma vez que ainda existe todo um gerenciamento do DOM e uma sequência infinita de requests para construção da página.

Mostrar todas as informações de uma tabela, que não tem quantidade fixa de resultados, mais cedo ou mais tarde se mostra uma má escolha arquitetural, uma vez que elas sempre tendem a crescer e gerar baixo desempenho não só na view, mas uma carga muito grande no servidor.

Adicionar uma paginação nesta lista certamente resolverá seu problema.